# Developing kerberos in tomcat using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, single-sign-on, kerberos

I am new to Kerberos and want a browser based sso authentication to the server using Kerberos.
Can anybody please provide a guide to setup Kerberos in jsp using tomcat. 
The client provides its username/password from a form in browser which forwards the request to the Kerberos server granting the session for the server he wants to access to.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos support is built in to Apache Tomcat. Download the latest 7.0.x release and follow the [Windows authentication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html) guide in the documentation.